# why does the order of arguments matter in here?

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

as far as I can remember, the order of the command arguments did not matter but here I see something else:

```
ffmpeg -f avi -i "s02e01.mkv" vcodec mpeg4 -b 4000k -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "converted.avi"
```

and this is the result:

```
s02e01.mkv: Operation not permitted
```

but after changing the place of "-f" and "-i" everything goes ok:

```
ffmpeg -i "s02e01.mkv" -f avi vcodec mpeg4 -b 4000k -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k "converted.avi"
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: In the ffmpeg library order of command line arguments is important. The key before the input file means that the parameter refers to the input file (in this case, specifying the format.)

Answer (score 5):

It's up to the program to decide what to do with the command line inputs it is given. Most programs don't care what order they are given because they are functionally distinct. But where some flags can optionally affect others the easiest way to implement it is through input ordering. ffmpeg is one such program. Its man page says:

> As a general rule, options are applied to the next specified file. Therefore, order is important, and you can have the same option on the command line multiple times.

gcc is another program that can catch you out; its man page says:

> You can mix options and other arguments.  For the most part, the order you use doesn't matter.  Order does matter when you use several options of the same kind; for example, if you specify -L more than once, the directories are searched in the order specified.  Also, the placement of the -l option is significant.